# WCF soap webservice as Windows service can't be reached

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a .NET 4.6 application that hosts a WCF soap webservice. It's pretty basic and it works fine when I run it in a classic .NET 4.6 desktop application under my own user.
However I want to run it as a Windows service under a service account.
I use 100% the exact same wcf code and service definition with the only difference that it's within a windows service, but it doesn't work. No response is returned.

So for example in a .NET 4.6 desktop application I can send POST soap requests and get replies, and browse the definition on http://10.10.10.10:8904/blabla?wsdl just fine.
When I run it as a Windows service under a service account, it doesn't respond. For example browsing to http://10.10.10.10:8904/blabla?wsdl doesn't give any response (in the browser it keeps spinning).

In netstat I can see Windows hosting on the port 8904.

If I enable WCF tracing to file I can see logs like this, so there seems to be some WCF activity at least:

```
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
    <ActivityName>Ontvang bytes op verbinding http://10.10.10.10:8904/blabla?wsdl.</ActivityName>
    <ActivityType>ReceiveBytes</ActivityType>
</ExtendedData>
```

I have also already added: netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8904/blabla/ user=Everyone

Any idea? Am I missing certain user rights? Does there need to be a WCF configuration difference between running as a desktop application and a windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to start the service from within a separate thread, and not from the main thread. Otherwise it locks up.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Managed code in the desktop application is different from the code snippets in the windows service. we usually use the LocalSystem account to run the Windows Service since WCF service requires the administrator privilege to listen to the machine port. In the OnStart method, it is necessary to open the service host in order to listen to the request.
Here are my code segments.

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1017");
        ServiceHost sh = null;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            try
            {
                sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true,
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");

                sh.Open();
                WriteLog($"Service is ready at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteLog($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()},{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}-----------------------------------------------------");
                WriteLog(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (sh != null && sh.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                sh.Close();
                WriteLog($"Service is closed at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
            }
        }

        public static void WriteLog(string text)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Mylog.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(text);
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "mydomain")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();

    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            Service1.WriteLog(string.Format("Wow, I have been called at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")));
            return $"Hello stranger,Now is {DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
        }

    }
```

After installing the service by using the installutil.exe tool and start the service, we are capable of accessing the service creation page.
[image]
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.